# Share Clipboard Between Ubuntu and Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: server, windows-8, remote-desktop, clipboard

I am trying to copy paste text between Windows Remote Desktop and Linux Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04 with Mate Desktop.

I have seen several posts that mention killing the rdpclip.exe process (on Windows) and restarting it. I can only imagine this pertains to an old version since rdpclip.exe isn't even running and I can copy paste between Windows machines just fine. However to test the idea, I started the rdpclip.exe program but this did not have any effect.

I also made sure that the clipboard is checked for my remote desktop connection.

In case it's relevant, I setup remote desktop by first installing the Mate 2D Desktop and then installing XRDP.

I am using Windows 8.1 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not running in the first place, did you check under..

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\Wds\rdpwd
```

..if the following entry of Type REG_SZ is present or missing?

```
„StartupPrograms“=“rdpclip“
```

Thanks to [this guy](http://bent-blog.de/remote-desktop-server-zwischenablage-funktioniert-nicht/) (German language).